# Question about setting up a VPN under Ubuntu

Tags: networking, vpn

I want to connect my Ubuntu PC to a VPN server (e.g. the Mozilla VPN, or a similar solution), and achieve the following two points:

- All programs (inclusive e.g. apt, pip, etc.) should have to use the VPN without any possibility to send or receive data via the normal internet connection. This should also be true for the OS.
- It should be impossible for any program to determine the real IP address or location of my PC

Is this possible?

As far as I know, it isn't possible if I directly connect to the VPN from my PC. But I was thinking about connecting an old laptop to the VPN, and sharing the VPN connection by creating WiFi-hotspot.

However, I'd also like to know if it's possible to achieve the same results by directly connecting to the VPN from the Ubuntu PC.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Can you edit you question to be more specific? Are you asking about how to start a VPN server or how to connect to one?

Comment: @sotirov I want to connect my PC to an existing VPN (not set up one myself).

Comment: If I understand you correct, you want to connect to the VPN from your older laptop and share the connection to Wi-Fi. You can do this. Please update your question with detail about the VPN server you want to connect to.

Comment: Please edit your question and indicate what kind of VPN you want to use. Is a corporate VPN server? Is it a commercial provider for home users? Are your own cloud based VPN server? What have you tried to say that "it is not possible"? How did you determine that apt pip etc do not use VPN? Which program did you use to find your real IP address while using the VPN? Try it out first. If it does not work, provide details.

Comment: By corporate VPN, I mean if you work for a company, say IBM, and you have to use their VPN for work. Examples off commercial VPN include NordVPN, Express VPN, etc.

Comment: @user68186 I updated my question. Honestly, I don't know yet which VPN server I want to use. I was thinking about using one of the usual payed services (such the Mozilla VPN), but I don't want to spend any money before I know if it's possible at all.

Comment: @user68186 Are these VPN services really going to force all outgoing traffic through the VPN connection? For example, I heard that many programs (such as apt or pip) are not using a VPN connection by default.

Comment: Mozzlla VPN, as far as I know, works only inside Firefox by design. Consider a more general VPN service provider. Google **best VPN for Linux** to begin with. Most VPN providers offer money back guarantee within the first number of days (7, 15, 30 etc.). Try and cancel if you hypothesis is correct.

Comment: @al-canonic When set up properly, *all* traffic goes over the VPN - apt included.  Providers like NordVPN work fine on Ububtu and route all traffic over their network but you need to use their client.  Very few offer Ubuntu-integrated out-of-the-box configs that work with just basic Ubuntu and network manager libs, etc.  Mozilla VPN is not one of those options though, its Firefox Only.

Comment: @Thomas Ward Thanks for your explanations. Just for clarification: My solution (to connect to the VPN on the laptop and then setting up a WiFi hotspot) should work for any VPN (as long as I can connect my Laptop to it)?

Comment: @al-canonic *theoretically* yes, however I can't guarantee the 'wifi hotspot' part will function.  That will require you to properly set up NAT rules on your system to masquerade and go out over the VPN tunnel.  That's a separate discussion unrelated to the VPN portion.

Comment: The proposed solution, setting up VPN on the laptop and using is Wi-Fi won't work with Firefox or Mozzlla VPN as that VPN lives inside Firefox. There is no way to make your Wi-Fi connection firm other computers go through Firefox in the laptop where Mozzlla VPN is installed.